# request localAddress times out

Tags: node.js, networking

Im using an rpi 4b as a node express server.

I have two network interfaces: eth0 and wlan0.
They both work by themselves but when both are connected and using eth0 as default, every time I specify {localAddress: /*wlan0 address*/} it times out.

```
const request = require('request');
const os = require('os');
const localAddress = os.networkInterfaces().wlan0[0].address
request({uri: 'http://ip.jsontable.com', localAddress}, console.log)
```

Comment: Do make sure that you are using the right network interface.

Comment: Yes. I tested both with localAddress as the ip address of the interface of both when only one interface was connected.